# Django admin inlines - how to remove empty records from create/update form

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using StackedInline to add related objects in my Django admin form (relation is one to many). The problem is that it renders three empty inline forms by default when creating new object like in this example:

[image]

What I want is to render only "Add" button because the related objects are so rare that most of the records don't have these (or at least single empty record) and my related object is much larger than the one on the pictures. It should look something like this example:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

In admin.py, I define inline like this with extra parameter set to null:

```
class OfficerAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Officer
    extra = 0
```

If I want one default empty inline, I set extra=1 etc.